# Error while removing not null constraint for the not primary key column in sap hana

Tags: null, hana, notnull

My hana table have NOT NULL constraint on some columns.

But when I am trying to remove that not null constraint from one of the column following error has occurred:

> Error: feature not supported: cannot add nullable constraints on primary key column

**Note:** *That column is not a  part of primary key.*

Syntax that I used for removing NOT NULL constraint:

Syntax :

```
Alter table table_name alter (column_name datatype null)
```

Kindly suggest the solution.

Comment: Please provide the complete DDL to create the table first and then alter it. Include all table storage parameter (ROW/COLUMN TABLE, PARTITIONING, etc. ) that apply. Also, which version of HANA are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to drop primary key first, by adding `DROP PRIMARY KEY` to your statement.
[Here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/20d329a6751910149d5fdbc4800f92ff.html) is documentation for alter table statement

Comment: i have dropped primary key already,it removes key from table but not null constraints remains on that columns and when we try to remove that not null constraint,we are getting above mentioned error...